# Makefile simple rule how to

Tags: makefile

Is there a simple way to achieve the following with a simple suffix rule (or other way)?

```
SRC = a.c b.c c.c d.c e.c
ASM = a.s b.s c.s d.s e.s

$(ASM) : $(SRC)
   gcc -S -O0 a.s a.c
   gcc -S -O0 b.s b.c
   ...
   gcc -S -O0 e.s e.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably split the target for every assembly output, something along the lines of (not tested):

```makefile
SRC = a.c b.c c.c d.c e.c
ASM = $(SRC:.c=.s)

%.s: %.c
    gcc -S -O0 $<
```

Considering that `gcc -S x.c` produces an `x.s` by default (see [`gcc(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)).